# python reuse code, parse add to list and print match line

Tags: python, regex

I am trying a code where:

List `a` contains: Benny and search in two.txt and prints matching line benny. And contains Adarsh and adds adarsh to list and should print the matching line of adarsh.

Coding:

```
import re
a=[]
with open('one.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        res = re.findall(r'(?:Dr[.](\w+))', line)
        if res: 
            a.extend(res)

print a

with open('two.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for key in a:
        for line in lines:
            if key in line:
                print line
        for ln1 in line          #<-obtained output lines        
        res = re.findall(r'(?:Dr[.](\w+))', ln1)
        if res: 
            a.extend(res)


        for key in a:
            for line in lines:
                if key in line:
                    print line
```

one.txt contains:

> Dr.Benny

two.txt contains:

> Benny is a good friend Dr.Adarsh
>
> Kim is a good boy
>
> I am good boy
>
> Adarsh and him are the best friends.

Output getting:

> Benny is a good friend Dr.Adarsh

Desired Output:

> Benny is a good friend Dr.Adarsh
>
> Adarsh and him are the best friends

Comment: Have you considered using loops? Removing the obvious duplication? If this code works, consider submitted it for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: its not working actually, my doubt was using any new for loops make my output!

Comment: Then please provide information on what it *is* doing. Errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)? Reduce the code to a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that replicates the issue.

Comment: edited the question and code,i hope now it will be easily understood!

Comment: So is that the output you want, or the output you get? Whichever, could you please also supply the other one, and make it clear which is which.

Comment: its the output i wanted!

Comment: So **what is the output you actually get**?!

Comment: @user3830379 It is good you are trying to provide complete running code. However, the code in your question is invalid - the loop `for ln1 in line` is missing `:` and it is not clear, what is expected body of the loop.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It just provides :Benny is a good friend Dr.Adarsh alone and doesnot search for adarsh.

Comment: @user3830379 please **edit the question** to include this along with the desired output.

Comment: @jonrsharpe fine and hoping for your answer!edited my question.

Comment: You're only searching for lines with `'Dr.'` in - why would you expect to get the other line, too?

Comment: because as i unclearly mentioned if the word attained in list it should print that line also

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24850796/python-print-matching-list-words-and-regex revised question,please visit!

Comment: @user3830379 don't just open another question, **fix this one**.

Comment: @jonrsharpe what more to provide for this question?if something is missing then that is due to my lack of knowledge!please address me what to provide

Comment: See @JanVlcinsky's comment; you need to provide an example that runs. Also, you seem to be extending `a` while iterating over it - that's not very wise.

Comment: @user3830379 You didn't answer to jonrsharpe's comment. You said why are you searching for lines with `'Dr.'` but you didn't say why are you searching **only** for these lines. Search also for the other pattern, so you'll get your expected result. It's unclear which part of this task you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of your code is fine, so we can simplify it to:

```
import re

a = ['Benny']
```

However, the second part makes no sense. You are trying to extend `a` while iterating over it, which could create a never-ending loop. I think what you want is:

```
with open('two.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines() # get lines from second file

b = [] # new names

for line in lines: # iterate once for the new names
    if any(name in line for name in a):
        b.extend(re.findall(r'(?:Dr[.](\w+))', line))

a += b # add new names to original names

for line in lines: # iterate again to display results
    if any(name in line for name in a):
        print line
```

Note that:

1. `list.extend` doesn't do anything if the list is empty, so there's no need to check; and
2. adding an optional whitespace character `'\s?'` to your regex and making the word boundary `'\b'` explicit would allow you to capture more sensibly-formatted names like `'Dr. Adarsh'` (see [demo](http://regex101.com/r/gV0wA9/2)).

Comment: yes u are almost close for what i exactly need, I mean over iterating again if it again finds Dr. then again it should add to list and print the line and so on till it finds all the Dr. for matching lines

Comment: i mean the never ending loop is what i needed,which will grow when it finds the new names and get that,is that your answer consisting of?

Comment: @user3830379 I have no idea what you're asking. This is why it's helpful to provide a clear example. Does my answer do what you want? Does it not? Does it do part of it?

Comment: if it consists of new Dr. in adarsh line then its not getting printed that is my problem.Eg,    Adarsh and him are the best friends Dr.Tilu
    
   /n Tilu is good #<-its not printing a new Dr. for adarsh.